# How to show message on click on the username on the same page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 div's: users_list and messages. I wrote the part of code which choose from DB usernames to whom was message sent. But how can I do the following:

I click on the username and in the right div it selects from db message column, text and shows it here for each user.

[image]

How can I do the next? You can writes your answers I will answer to them.

```
<% @users_list.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%= user.message_for %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

I wrote the code:

```
def show_message
    Message.all_messages(session[:username]).from
end

function message_for(username){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/show_message',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            to: username
        },
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    })
}
```

Message.rb model def:

```
def self.all_messages(to)
    @to = params[:to]
    Message.where(to: to).order(date: :desc)
end
```

And it prints the next error:

```
Started POST "/show_message" for 81.21.82.67 at 2015-01-08 08:26:29 -0500
Processing by MessagesController#show_message as */*
Parameters: {"to"=>"alizade"}
Completed 500  in 14ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template messages/show_message, application/show_message
```

**UPDATE**
My route file:

```
resources :users
resources :bookworms
resources :sessions
resources :covers
resources :messages

root 'bookworm#index'

get '/profile' => 'bookworm#profile'
get '/messages' => 'messages#index'
get '/login' => 'users#login'

post '/show_messages' => 'messages#show_message'
```

Comment: Why you have defined it as post request? Can you tell me route definition for the same

Comment: @TriveniBadgujar Okay. I removed the method line. I updated my question and added my route file content

Answer (score 0):

Define route in route file

```
get '/show_message' => 'messages#show_message'
```

and following js code

```
function message_for(username){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/show_message',
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(response){
            alert(response);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me the data : { id : username }? When I click it sends to my function `username`. Later starts work /show_message. How username data relate with this def? Because, here is the error for my data : { to : username } : Processing by MessagesController#show_message as */*
  Parameters: {"to"=>"alizade"}
Completed 500  in 6ms

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:18:in `show_message'

Comment: So on what basis you are going to fetch messages? As per my understanding of your requirement you want to show messages for user. Then how will you get user? Either you have to pass user id or name. If you dont need it then just remove it.

Comment: I have a DB table(id, to, from, message, date). On click on the user I want to take from table - messages - which send the user(FROM). How can I do it? If you have a question ask me. I updated the question. And I do not need GET, I need a POST method without changing the URL